# matplotlib, including more than one defined variable on legend label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to include two or more variables, previously defined in the code, to the label for the legend or when plotting text. For example, I have a bunch of functions plotted and I want the equations for each on the legend. If I just have something like y = Ax, where A is found by fitting a function to some data I would write something like:

```
 plt.plot(x, y, label='y = %.2f x' %A)
```

and on the legend I would see the real value of A on the equation. Now if I want to do the same with y = Ax + B and I go

```
 plt.plot(x, y, label='y = %.2f x + %.2f' %A %B)
```

I get an error. Most of the ways I tried gave me syntax error and I got one that said not enough arguments for format string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
 plt.plot(x, y, label='y = %.2f x + %.2f' %(A, B))
```

Comment: Thanks! that works :) ... I think it was the only combination I didnt try :P

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, you can use the more flexible [python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) using the `.format()` method. For example:

```
 plt.plot(x, y, label='y = {0:.2f} x + {1:.2f}'.format(A,B))
```